# Java Rest Api with web browser

Tags: java, rest

So I created a simple java rest api that lets a user enter a movie or search for a movie from mysql database (using postman). My question is I want to create a simple web application that lets the user enter the criteria for a movie, send that data to the api to process it. I am not sure what do I have to use for the web application. Can I use HTML, javascript, jquery for it, or do I have to use jsp and servlets because of Java.

Comment: You can use anything to send requests, it does not have to match your server implementation language

Comment: You should be spending more time reading about HTTP based services.

Answer (score -1):

To simplify your code I suggest using JQuery for the API calls. If you want something more elaborated, learn Anguar 4. It's not hard and it works very nice.

HTML, JSF, JSP it doesn't matter. If you want to use JSP "because of Java", you probably don't need to build REST services.

Comment: Random anonymous down-votes. I have answered the colleague question, this is all he/she wants to know. Try to contribute, say something useful instead of down-voting.